# AuthenticationManager throws StackOverflowError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I am trying to implement the web security configuration without implementing the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. But when I try to authenticate the User AuthenticationManager gives me stackOverFlow error. Here is the web security config class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();

    }
}
```

Here is how I try to access the authenticationManager.

```
@Service
public class AuthService {
  
  @Autowired    
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
          
            public Optional<Authentication> authenticateUser(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
                return Optional.ofNullable(authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword())));
            }
}
```

Here is the error itself.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:67) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy151.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy151.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy151.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy151.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
```

Comment: Missing some elements here but I believe that `authenticationManager.authenticate` in your method is causing it to call itself through `authenticateUser`. You need to change the wiring or the method

Comment: Having same issue. I get a JdkDynamicAopProxy instead of authenticationManager auto wired Bean

Comment: @Camille I have the same issue in my spring boot microservice example. As I still couldn't fix the issue, it is possible to help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-servicetest-and-controllertest-for-junit-throwing-ja

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this problem,but I use below code

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
        throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

seeing this problem:

```
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:211)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy72.authenticate(Unknown Source)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Actually,I see other guys answers and tried more than twice and find out below method is feasible:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig{
    
        //rewrite loadByUsername in UserDetailsServiceImpl and I inject it in Spring Container
        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
            authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
        }
}
```

which works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I needed an AuthenticationManager for creating an AuthenticationFilter. I ended up with this solution:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> authenticationManagerResolver = r -> authenticationManagerBuilder.getOrBuild();
    AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerResolver, ...);
    // ...
    return http.build();
}
```